# Database indices that cover only one value

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g

I have huge table (millions of records) in which a few hundreds to a few thousands are marked by a boolean field (value = 1 instead of 0).

I only care for records which are true (value = 1). Is there a way to create an index which only 'indexes' these records? What kind of indices should I use?

```
select count(*) 
from records 
where boolean_field = 1
```

Environment: Oracle 10g (but I'm also interested in comments about other dbms)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could make your "false" value be null rather than 0, you would achieve the result you want.

Otherwise, you could create a function-based index like this:

```
create index idx on recors (case boolean_field when 1 then 1 end);
```

That would only index the 1s, but for Oracle to use it in your queries your queries would have to be like:

```
select * from records where case boolean_field when 1 then 1 end = 1;
```

Comment: If going the function-based index route, I would suggest making a view with the case logic baked in and have everything query that view instead of the table.  This will help ensure that all people writing queries against the table will be able to utilize the index.

Comment: I kinda dislike both variants, but I'll go for the frist one! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a typical case for bitmap indexes in oracle.

```
create bitmap index bool_field_index on recors(boolean_field)
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#i2062403

Comment: Bitmap indexes impose a heavy cost on DML, which renders them unsuitable for OLTP systems.  And these days, even data warehouses may be updated in near real time rather than in batch mode.  Which doesn't mean a bitmap index isn't a viable solution, just that it is only going to be helpful in certain situations.